# Error during compilation?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, jframe, components, identifier

so I have been making a code regarding `JPizza.java` and I have come to the point where I get this error:

```
    JPizza.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
  music = getAudioClip(getCodeBase(),"katy_perry-roar.mid");
                       ^
  symbol:   method getCodeBase()
  location: class JPizza
  1 error
```

I have been trying to figure out why it is giving me these error, but
 I can't find the main issue here? Is it because I forgot to define
 a method? For the getCodeBase() and CodeBase() I tried to define it as `CodeBase() =    getCodeBase()` and it then shifts the error to getAudioClip

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class JPizza extends JFrame implements ItemListener, ActionListener
 {
  FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout();
  JLabel companyName = new JLabel("PizzaPalooza");
  JComboBox<String> sizeBox = new JComboBox<String>();
  JLabel sizeList = new JLabel("Size List");
  JComboBox<String> toppingBox = new JComboBox<String>();
  JLabel toppingList = new JLabel("Topping List");
  JTextField totPrice = new JTextField(10);
  JLabel orderName = new JLabel("Name of Order");
  JTextField oName = new JTextField(15);
  JLabel listenLabel = new JLabel("Listen to our theme!");
  JButton playButton = new JButton("Play");
  JButton stopButton = new JButton("Stop");
  JLabel headLabel = new JLabel ();
  AudioClip music;
  int totalPrice = 0;
  int sizeNum, toppingNum;
  int sPrice, tPrice, sumPrice;
  int[] sizePrice = {0,7,9,11,14};
  int[] toppingPrice = {0,0,1,1,1,1};
  String output;
   public void init()
    {
     Container con = getContentPane();
     con.setLayout (new FlowLayout());
     con.add(headLabel);
     con.add(listenLabel);
     con.add(playButton);
     con.add(stopButton);
     playButton.addActionListener(this);
     stopButton.addActionListener(this);
     music = getAudioClip(getCodeBase(),"katy_perry-roar.mid");
    }

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
     {
      Object source = e.getSource();
      if(source == playButton)
       music.loop();
      else
       music.stop();
     }
```

for this, but I do not understand what this means?

Comment: Look at the line above...

Comment: The line `JLabel headLabel = new JLabel` looks kind of trimmed.  That could be the problem.  It should be `JLabel headLabel = new JLabel("Some String");`

Comment: Where did you define the method `getCodeBase`? Or is it built-in to a class (which one?)?

Comment: @Flight I assumed because you were inputting the song from another source, you would use getCodeBase and it was defined in `java.awt.event.*` per my Java Professor.

Answer (score 2):

Compilation problem lies in the line just above. You are missing the JLabel constructor brackets and semicolon, in the line

```
  JLabel headLabel = new JLabel
```

should be:

```
  JLabel headLabel = new JLabel();
```

Comment: Can you help me with the `JPizza.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
  music = getAudioClip(getCodeBase(),"katy_perry-roar.mid");
                       ^
  symbol:   method getCodeBase()
  location: class JPizza` error? I still do not get it, for the getCodeBase() and CodeBase() I tried to define it as CodeBase() = getCodeBase() and it then shifts the error to getAudioClip

Comment: `JFrame` is not an `Applet`.